# Implementation of Gale-Shapley algorithm for allignment of ontologies

Tags: matching, ontology

Okay here is my problem. I have to implement the Gale-Shapley algorithm for the alignment of two ontologies. I read the first 200 pages of the book "Ontology Matching" by Jerome Euzenat and Pavel Shvaiko and now I understand some of the basics of ontology matching but the problem is that the more I read the more confused I become. I really think that the problem is relatively easy but I really can't get around it and I am not getting clear instructions from  my professor as they insist that I should decide everything on my own. The problem is that I don't understand the whole process. I understand the Stable Marriage Problem, I understand the basics of ontology matching but I can't seem to "connect" everything. If somebody could explain to me how the whole thing should look and how to start (the basics of a Design Document) I will be incredibly grateful.